# Select specific value from JSON list with SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json

Suppose I have a table column with person data organized as a JSON array, with categories and names.
In SQL, I can then easily select the data for a specific element in the array:

SELECT JSON_VALUE('{ "Persons": [{"PersonCat":"1","Name":"John"},{"PersonCat":"2","Name":"Henry"}]}','$.Persons[0].Name') AS SelectedPerson

I will then get "John".

But what if I want the person with "PersonCat" = 2? And null if PersonCat does not exist in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible to do this with the `JSON_VALUE` method, but it is possible using [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

SET @json = '{ "Persons": [{"PersonCat":"1","Name":"John"},{"PersonCat":"2","Name":"Henry"},{"Name":"Bob"}]}'

SELECT[PersonCat], [Name]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Persons')
  WITH (
    PersonCat NVARCHAR(512) '$.PersonCat',
    [Name] NVARCHAR(512) '$.Name'
  )
```

You can then add a `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` to find the relevant PersonCat value (note: where the PersonCat property is missing from the array entry, the PersonCat column will be NULL)

Comment: Thank you Duncan, I’ll go for this solution!

Comment: @Dan If you found the answer useful please could you mark it as an accepted answer so that other users can find it more easily, thanks.